# Не проксируются запросы в Scrapy

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver, proxy, scrapy

Всем доброго дня.
Нужно спарсить данные с сайта https://www.pinnacle.com/en/, доступ с территории РФ ограничен ->
пытаюсь использовать прокси в Scrapy.
Пробовал и в одиночные запросы вписывать прокси и устанавливать вот это https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies

Все время ода и та же ошибка:

```
    2020-07-16 16:50:44 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.pinnacle.com/en/>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/n30n/Run/DFS_math/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
        return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
    twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived:
 [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'pinnacle_parser'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['pinnacle_parser.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'pinnacle_parser.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 10
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 105,
    # 'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 500,
}

# Proxy list containing entries like
# http://host1:port
PROXY_LIST = '/home//Run/pinnacle_parser/proxy'

# Proxy mode
# 0 = Every requests have different proxy
# 1 = Take only one proxy from the list and assign it to every requests
# 2 = Put a custom proxy to use in the settings
PROXY_MODE = 2

# # If proxy mode is 2 uncomment this sentence :
CUSTOM_PROXY = "http://217.172.190.254:5836"
```

С чем связана данная ошибка?Каким образом сайт может дополнительно препятствовать скраппингу?

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте не основной сайт, а зеркала пинки парсить.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге тогда я так и сделал

Comment: а что за проект ты ведешь ? можем пообщаться ?

Comment: Dmirty_osint мой Тг  / напиши , оч интересно  пообщаться